# problem with Admob - wrong link with app in playstore

Tags: android, admob

I was doing tests with admob, I innocently linked an existing application in the playstore that is not mine, obviously I was not going to create it, I clicked on the close button but Admob linked the applications.

Obviously I do not have any ad unit, but I can not modify or delete the application to remove in link between that admob app and the playstore app.

Can Admob suspend my account for this error?
Can remove that link between the Admob app and the Playstore app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete an app from your AdMob account, although you can hide it as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6061403?hl=en&ref_topic=7384648)

Admob doesn't have any direct policy about connecting someone else app to your account, so no one can tell you for sure but it's quite improbable that they will suspend your account. And I have this opinion on the base that in the "Adding A Link To Your App" [documentation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3034835?hl=en) , they have only warned us like this(only):

> Make sure you link the correct app. You can't change it later.

I have read somewhere that in earlier Admob version you could delete your app from App Settings page (and that version is still live, but not accessible from the Admob URL, you may search for it)

In the end, I'll say just hiding your app is enough.